# How to insert data to remote database from local computer?

Tags: php, remote-access

I am having shared server with cpanel.I have mysql database on server.I want to insert or update data to remote database by running php script on my local computer.Please give me solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Make connection to that database then everything will be working fine

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, if you have a question, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and we will be glad to help if the question allows us to, we are here to help, not just feed you code..

Comment: I tried to connect database but it gives Error no 2002 connected party did not respond after some time.

Comment: **Read @Naruto comment.**

Comment: are you trying to connect from your local machine, to an hosted database? normally database connections are blocked from anything other than localhost. as they should be

Comment: i am getting below error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. –

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* mysql database properties */
    $host = 'mydomain.com'; // or I.P address of domain
    $user = 'database user name'; 
    $pass = 'database password';
    $database = 'database Name';
    $table = 'Table Name';

    /* Database Connection */
    $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $name = 'Amir Khan';
    $age = '27';
    /* Insert query */
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO $table (name, age) VALUES ('$name', '$age');";
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

    /*update query too same like above*/

    /* you can go mysqli or PDO  for better query structure*/
```

Comment: i am getting below error:                                                                                               A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: please check connection string properly

Answer (score 0):

This is one line query to connect into MySQL remote database and insert from local csv file

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=',' --lines-terminated-by="\n" --local -u <username> -p'<password>' -h <hostname> -P <port> <database>  <tablename>.csv
```